# Stack overflow with Fortran

Tags: fortran, stack-overflow

I've written a program with Compaq Visual Fortran. The program is ok and is running correctly in many cases. The case I'm working on now is bigger, with bigger input data files and when I run the program I have the following error:

> forrtl: severe(170): Program exception - stack overflow

I have the `editbin.exe` program installed but I really don't know how to use it. When typing

```
editbin /STACK:4000000 DFDEV.exe
```

it tells me that it can't open `DFDEV.exe`, even if I'm inside the directory containing this program (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDEV98\BIN).
I really don't know how to solve this problem and in every topic I've found about this subject on internet there's no explanation on how to use this editbin program.

Comment: Perhaps you have to provide the full path to `DFDEV.exe` when running `editbin`. If you just type `editbin` at the command line without any other command-line input, [you will get a usage statement that summarises the editbin options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However, if you don't know how to use editbin, what makes you think it is the correct tool for the task (of debugging your program exception error)?

Comment: If your problem is that your data is too big to fit on the stack, you could consider allocating on the heap instead.

Comment: +1 to @DavidHeffernan's comment; particularly with older fortran programs that don't make use of dynamic allocation, stack overflow almost always means that large, static arrays in subroutines or functions have grown too large to fit on the stack.   Depending on your OS, there are work arounds, or you can convince your compiler to allocate large arrays on the heap, but best of all is to start working towards not having such large static arrays at all and instead allocate them as necessary.

Comment: if the data is very big you could try some flag like -share to allocate it in the heap. I don't know if the correct flag is -share at least in the intel compiler this flag is -share-intel

Comment: @chris: thank you for your replies.i tried editbin since I found on the net that throught this tool, one can increase the stack. I've allocated all the arrays. It's the first time this happens because th input are very big.

Comment: @armando: I don't know how to deal with flags with the compaq visual fortran program

Comment: @David: how can I allocate on the heap? what does it mean?

Comment: In Fortran I believe this is referred to as "dynamic allocation". But I know nothing of Fortran so I don't know the syntax.

Comment: @chris: I forgot: i typed the command directly from the directory where the DFDEV.exe is; I think it should be ok. Editbin is a software that is installed with the fortran package. It should be a solution, but I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: to everyone, I don't know if it can help someone, but in the options of the software (Compaq Visual Fortran), under project settings, there's a tab (named 'link') ; if one choose as categorie: 'ouput' and put values in 'reserve' and 'commi't, the problem seems to be solved (personnaly, I've put 4000000 and 4000000) and it's ok now. Maybe lower value could be ok.

Comment: The Fortran language standard does not have the concept of stack and heap.   Some compilers have a compile time options to control whether or not arrays are placed on the stack.  Allocatable arrays are very likely to go on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: Can you post the matrix allocation code so we can suggest changes? Also have you debugged the code and verified where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I also found the compiler "help" unhelpful. The programmer's guide offers some words on stack and heap allocation that can be found via a search on "commit", with hints that EDITBIN.EXE can be used to modify an already-compiled .exe file. As later mentioned there is also the compiler option Project>Settings>Link>Output leading to the possibility of specifying larger values but little guidance on what values.

There is a compiler option to assume AUTOMATIC for storage declared in subroutines, however, some programmes may well turn out to rely on data being stored "static" between calls and not have diligently specified SAVE. I have been careful with SAVE, and have not noticed any effect with "automatic" selected. In my case trouble began after I introduced a little recursion (automatically available in Burroughs fortran - the RECURSIVE keyword is otiose), but stack storage is also used for temporary variables (possibly array-sized) and copy-in, copy-out parameters such as array sections, or, for example, passing an array of type blob, where blob is a compound entity containing say an integer and you want to present the integers as an array as in A(i:j).Fred, where in storage, consecutive elements of Fred are not in fact adjacent (with stride = 1) because the blob contains other items as well.

Anyway, I started to use allocated arrays (so as to have ragged arrays rather than a(bigenough,n) and the like) and other changes and I have just now checked and found that the setting has reverted to the default (blank entry), no doubt due to intervening reinstallations on a new computer after a power supply failed.